# Is there an error in loading Page due to stylesheet blocked by Google Bot?

Tags: php, android, html, wordpress, robots.txt

I have created my first Wordpress blog site. There are lots of content in this site including images and Google Maps. This page shows up as mobile-friendly in Google Search Console, but with some error while loading the pages.

A few of the errors I get are as follows.

```
https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id - Blocked by Robots.txt
https://sitename.com/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/eicons/css/elementor-icons.min.css?ver=5.6.2  (Stylesheet - Other error)
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Ramakrishna%20beach%20visakhapatanam&t=m&z=10&output=embed&iwloc=near - Googlebot blocked by robots.txt
```

Could anyone help me fix these errors? Please let me know. Once again, thank you for all your support.